# How to explore a python file from commandline

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I have a python file with no `argparse` implementation in its `__main__`, yet, I'm interested in having a look at the functions and modules implemented in it from the commandline. I'm tempted to write a function to perform such *exploration* but I wanted to find out first whether this is already available.

EDIT 1: to make it more concrete, I'm interested in names of functions and classes + their docs.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Why can't you just open the file?

Comment: `cat my_prog.py` would be a good place to start.

Comment: Because the file could have 10k lines of code that I don't have time to parse through them nor that I'm interested in the code. I just need names of functions that tell me what can be done.
@defladamouse

Comment: `grep -w def filename.py`?

Comment: What does `argparse` have to do with this?

Comment: Just use `grep def`?

Comment: @Barmar if `argparse` is implemeted, you can easily say `-h` and will tell you what functions are there and how to use them

Comment: If you also want their documentation strings, you'll need a script or tool that does some more elaborate parsing. You could write it in Python using the `ast` module.

Comment: @AlexDeft No it wouldn't. That just tells you what arguments the script expects, assuming it even takes command line arguments.

Comment: @Barmar Alright, safe, so my point is implementing argparse for every file is laborious, so I thought if there is a tool that can serve an approximate functionality, it would save significant amount of time.

Comment: @AlexDeft I think what you may be looking for is something like [python-fire](https://github.com/google/python-fire), which can automatically generate a CLI from a class. However this would require you to mutate the file you want to observe, and that it is implemented as a class.

Comment: @zr0gravity7 That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you! everyone else are just not getting the point. Please post as an answer.

Comment: @zr0gravity7 fire doesn't require classes. It works on just module-level functions just fine

Comment: Note, the easiest way if you just want to look at the docs is to just open up a python repl, then `import some_module` then just use `help(some_module)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for this tip. I've tried `python -m fire mypyfile.py` and it seems to produce very similar result to your suggestion except that it works from terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for a tool like [python-fire](https://github.com/google/python-fire).

From the repository:

> Python Fire is a library for automatically generating command line interfaces (CLIs) from absolutely any Python object. [...] Python Fire helps with exploring existing code or turning other people's code into a CLI.

It is available as a package on pip.

Comment: Actually, this package is so cool that there is an option where you *don't neeed to mutate the file* in as you mentioned in the comments. They call it `entry point` method. Absolutely genuis.

Comment: Very cool. Haven't used it myself yet, which is why I am a bit fuzzy on the way it interfaces with the file, but I am glad it works for your use case!